# Cannot Resolve Symbol "Place.Field"

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, placeautocompletefragment

I am trying to migrate new Auto Complete Place Picker I have updated library from `"com.google.android.gms:play-services"` to new `"com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0"` and implemented `SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment`.

All works fine however the error I am getting is:

> `"Place.Field" Cannot resolve symbol 'Field'`

Below is my code:

```
 // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
 SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);


//List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
// Specify the types of place data to return.
supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
    }
});

supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
```

Can you help me solve this error:

> `"Place.Field" Cannot resolve symbol 'Field'`

Comment: Post more code!

Comment: It seems like you load another ```Place``` class. Show your imports too.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that you import the correct Place class.

```
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment class is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment). Please use the AutocompleteSupportFragment class instead. Refer to [Google's migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_client_library) and the [Place Autocomplete's guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment).

```
// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
AutocompleteSupportFragment supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

//List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
// Specify the types of place data to return.
supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
    }
});

supportPlaceAutocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
```

Hope this helps!